# Export csv from excel with foreign characters for import into MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

When I export this from Excel in a csv file to import into MySQL

> Bl Michał Sopoćko, Priest

I get this

> Bl Micha? Sopo?ko

Is there a way to export the file to have the right characters?

Comment: What collation do you use on the DB and on the connection? There must be the same. I recommend you the 1250 (Central European) character set (or any latin 7 oriented). Also how do you see it on the CSV? Please provide the method that you use for import, it will be significant at the moment to give you the best approach or solution. Be aware if you use UTF-8 (by the way I don't think you use this because the transformation is only on 1 character.)

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the encoding option that was specified during the export from Excel (in save dialog -> Tools button -> Web options -> Encoding Tab).

Next try to convert database table to this encoding:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET <character_set> COLLATE <collate_name>
```